# Put Json/Jsonp data to a form using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The chinese map service "Tencent map" provides a Json/Jsonp URL to get the location information, the URL is like:

http://apis.map.qq.com/ws/geocoder/v1/?location=39.984154,116.307490&key=OB4BZ-D4W3U-B7VVO-4PJWW-6TKDJ-WPB77&get_poi=1

Assume that I fill the latitude and longitude into a form, how to use JS/JQ to get the Json date and fill the "pois"(which in the json-> result -> pois ) data to a drop-down menu in the form?

The html I wrote is like:

```
<from>
    <lable>Oraginal GPS coordinates</lable></br>
    <input type="text" id="geo_latitude" name="geo_latitude" value="39.86343486063931">
    <input type="text" id="geo_longitude" name="geo_longitude" value="116.37321682380312">
<button onclick="getLocation()">GET it</button>
    <select id="geo_spot" name="geo_spot">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The Js is:(to make it jsonp I added "?output=jsonp" in the url to make it Jsonp to avoid Cross domain error)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("geo_latitude").value);
        var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("geo_longitude").value);
       var url='http://apis.map.qq.com/ws/geocoder/v1/?output=jsonp&location='+lat+','+lng+'&key=OB4BZ-D4W3U-B7VVO-4PJWW-6TKDJ-WPB77&get_poi=1&callback=?';
       jQuery.ajax({
         url:url,
         dataType:'jsonp',
         processData: true,
         type:'get',
         jsonp: "callback",
         contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
         success:function(data){
           alert(jsonp.result.pois);
         },
         error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
           alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
           alert(textStatus);
         }});
       });
```

My target is to add up all Pois date in Jsonp into that drop down  options, but after tried and tried, I can't even get the date....

Can you point out the mistake of my code? That would be very helpful!

I put a sample here so you can test my MISTAKE http://fireso.com/geo.html

PS, I can't modify the server part code, and have to use the api in a different domain, so the only way is working with the html js part.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: inside your success try console.log(data) - I think that will give you what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ajax API: The success function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified, a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

Inside your success use the `data` parameter, this is the answer from the server, so if you use `console.log(data)` you'll see the json object you are looking for.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:url,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    processData: true,
    type:'get',
    jsonp: "callback",
    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        // this should exists (if service sends it)
        alert(data.result.pois);
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
        alert(textStatus);
    }});
 });
```

Comment: Thank you Axel, you solved my problem! I modified the code as you taught me, it works perfectly!